# msmtp vs msmtp-mta package, which one to choose?

Tags: ubuntu, email, email-client, mta, msmtp

when installing `msmtp` under Debian/Ubuntu, which package should I choose, msmtp or msmtp-mta? what's the differences between them?

All the help articles I read install `msmtp` *only*, but isn't `msmtp-mta`,  the regular MTA, a better option?

Also, All the help articles I read config `msmtp` using *merely* a `~/.msmtprc` file, not system-wide, however, how about those cron jobs that send mails to `root`? How should I take care of them as well?

Thx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Msmtp), a great resource in general for all Linux operating systems, explains that `msmtp-mta` merely creates an alias for `sendmail`. This means you will have broader support for programs that require a sendmail compatible system.

There is an [existing question](https://serverfault.com/questions/632250/what-mailer-does-cron-use-to-send-mail) which discusses how to configure the mailing system of `cron`. However, again, I would just recommend the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cron#Example_with_msmtp) which explains that `msmtp-mta` will probably cause cron to Just Work.

Comment: Should be noted that cron is usually among programs that "require a sendmail compatible system" at the standard path.

Answer (score 4):

The [package description for `msmtp-mta`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/msmtp-mta) documents that it is a wrapper which will pull in `msmtp` as a dependency anyway.

> This package provides the regular MTA program.

This is somewhat obscure, but apparently means `sendmail` and `newaliases`.

[The package's file listing](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/msmtp-mta/filelist) reveals exactly what it contains.  As of right now (version 1.6.6-1) it contains the following files:

```
/usr/bin/newaliases
/usr/lib/sendmail
/usr/sbin/sendmail
/usr/share/doc/msmtp-mta/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/msmtp-mta/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/msmtp-mta/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/msmtp-mta
/usr/share/man/man1/newaliases.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/sendmail.8.gz
```

(In case you are unfamiliar with Debian packages, the stuff in `/usr/share/doc/mssmtp-mta` is just standard metadata for the package, and the `/usr/share/lintian/overrides` are specifics for the `lintian` package integrity checker, probably to say that it's okay for it to ship the same binaries as some other packages which also implement the legacy Sendmail command-line API.)

So in other words, if you require `sendmail` on your system, install the MTA package; otherwise the base package should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ tripleee, upvoting. but please allow me to give the answer to @ QasimK, who needs points more than us.

Comment: Sure (-: I'm somehow finally back above 1000 for other reasons now :-)